# Remote port forward to ldap hanging

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I have a windows machine (LOCAL), a Centos 7 VM (VM) and an LDAP (LDAP) I need to talk to through VM.

LOCAL can ssh into VM, and can independently talk to LDAP.

VM can't talk to LOCAL or LDAP directly

I executed a command on LOCAL like

`ssh -R 389:LDAP:389 VM`

Now inside VM I can do

`curl ldap://localhost/...`, providing authentication, and it works, almost. The appropriate response is returned but the connection hangs.

Why is it hanging, how can I fix this? I have full control over the VM, I have partial control over LOCAL and no control over LDAP. I have no control over any infrastructure I talk to.

I want to be able to do this because I am deploying an openshift cluster on a number of vms, openshift should be authenticated via a particular ldap. With the present configuration (for which curl hangs) the integration with ldap is not working. I have integrated openshift with an ldap docker image I spun up on the network that VM is able to talk to and it worked fine, leading me to believe this hanging is what is causing the problem.

If I am on a machine running an ldap, then I can do

`ssh -R 400:localhost:389 localhost`

At which point

`curl ldap://localhost:400/...` works fine (no hanging)

which is a bit mystifying

Comment: Clarification please. You write, "_LOCAL can ssh into VM and talk to LDAP._". Do you mean that LOCAL can ssh into the VM and thence talk to LDAP, or that LOCAL can ssh to the VM but it can separately also talk to LDAP?

Comment: @roaima the latter

Answer (score 1):

Worked out the issue, the hanging when curling is actually some general issue regarding curl and particular ldap settings.

https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/622

> This occurs when:
>
> The ldap backend used by your curl installation is openldap: probably
>   the case on Debian. Queries are made to a server that returns
>   referrals: M$AD is one of them :-( External ldap configuration allows
>   automatic referrals chasing. There is no easy way to support automatic
>   referrals chasing in curl yet. As a workaround, I can suggest you
>   disable this feature by ldap configuration ("REFERRALS off" in
>   ldap.conf): this will release the hang. Of course, this will also miss
>   the results from referrals, but in the current curl's state, they
>   won't be returned anyway.

More details: https://curl.haxx.se/mail/lib-2016-01/0101.html

Openshift wasn't working with ldap due to unrelated networking issues